# Зависание приложения при использовании Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

Нужно создать элементарный проигрыватель видео на WinForms (не встроить COM-объект, а "ручками"). Решил использовать Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video. Версия .NET в проекте - 4.5. Система - Windows7 64 bit. Добавил ссылки на:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\Microsoft.DirectX.dll
```

Написал простейший код:

```
//...
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

namespace VideoPlayer
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        Video video;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenMedia(string filename)
        {
            video = new Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video(filename);
            video.Owner = pnlView;
            video.Play();
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofdOpenDialog.Filter = "Файлы мультимедиа (*.avi)|*.avi";
            ofdOpenDialog.Multiselect = false;

            if (ofdOpenDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ofdOpenDialog.FileName);
                    //OpenMedia(ofdOpenDialog.FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге, в таком виде (когда вызов метода OpenMedia закоментирован) приложение запускается, диалог работает нормально. НО стоит раскоментировать вызов, как приложение наглухо виснет сразу при попытке вызова метода!

Обратите внимание. Не падает с ошибкой времени исполнения внутри метода. А виснет на его вызове, причем наглухо. Отладчик показывает нормальную обработку MessageBox, а потом при заходе в метод виснет студия. Когда код из метода был прямо в обработчике события - приложение зависало сразу же при старте (не срабатывал брейк-поинт даже на первом операторе в обработчике). Я потому и вынес в метод, чтобы выявить и изолировать точку зависания. Try-catch тоже не срабатывает, что лишний раз показывает не runtime ошибку, а ошибку JIT компиляции (как я предполагаю).

Такого аномального поведения студии я еще не видел. Поясните, пожалуйста, что это может быть и как это лечить?

Comment: А если запустить в отдельном потоке? Может оно у вас нормально работает.

Comment: Если бы оно работало нормально, то отладчик, как минимум, бы позволил посмотреть вызов функции с заходов в нее (по F11). Он же намертво виснет в момент нажатия F11, когда курсор выполнения стоит на вызове функции OpenMedia.

Comment: P.S. Задача уже не так актуальна, поскольку я прикрутил элемент управления WPF на WinForm'у - MediaElement, через ElementHost. Он то работает как надо. Но это не решает описанной мной тут проблемы, поэтому хотелось бы разобраться и с зависанием.